# How to ensure that columns are contained within a row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a css grid system with six columns. You can see the output of the html and css [at this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/bggwoecx/). The problem appears to be that the columns are overflowing the rows they are supposed to be contained in. For example, even though a row should be able to hold six 'size 1' columns, the sixth column in my example is spilling over into another row. How would I fix this so that the desired number of columns for each row doesn't exceed the width of the row?

```
<div class="grid-container outline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1"><p>col-1</p></div> 
            <div class="col-1"><p>col-1</p></div> 
            <div class="col-1"><p>col-1</p></div> 
            <div class="col-1"><p>col-1</p></div> 
            <div class="col-1"><p>col-1</p></div> 
            <div class="col-1"><p>col-1</p></div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2"><p>col-2</p></div> 
            <div class="col-2"><p>col-2</p></div> 
            <div class="col-2"><p>col-2</p></div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3"><p>col-3</p></div> 
            <div class="col-3"><p>col-3</p></div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

css

```
.grid-container{
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1200px;      
}

/*-- cleafix hack -- */ 
.row:before, 
.row:after {
    content:"";
      display: table ;
    clear:both;
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left; 
    min-height: 1px; 
    width: 16.66%; 
    /*-- gutter -- */
    padding: 12px; 
    background-color: #FFDCDC;
}

.col-1{ width: 16.66%; }
.col-2{ width: 33.33%; }
.col-3{ width: 50%;    }
.col-4{ width: 66.66%; }
.col-5{ width: 83.33%; }
.col-6{ width: 100%;   }

.outline, .outline *{
    outline: 1px solid #F6A1A1; 
}

/*-- some extra column content styling --*/
[class*='col-'] > p {
 background-color: #FFC2C2; 
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center; 
 color: white; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for:

```
div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bggwoecx/1/)**

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: took you long enough.